# C# Array specific value

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have a code in C# that I want to return only a single item from the array, what I currently have is, it returns all the result as following:

```
  1  This transaction has been approved. 
  2  NRO6CL 
  3  Y 
  4  2223032442 
  5  Sample Transaction 
  6  19.99 
  7  CC
```

All I need to do is, get 19.99 from the array. not everything in that array as shown above. The code below displays all the elements in the array.

```
    Array response_array = post_response.Split('|');
    resultSpan.InnerHtml += "<OL> \n";
    foreach (string value in response_array)
    {
        resultSpan.InnerHtml += "<LI>" + value + "&nbsp;</LI> \n";
    }
    resultSpan.InnerHtml += "</OL> \n";
```

Comment: Have you declared your array with its size?

Comment: Array index starts at 0, so `response_array[6]` actually points to `CC`

Comment: thank you, even with that i get the same error Error 6 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Array'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is unclear and seemingly self-contradictory. Why have a `foreach` loop if you only want one element from the result? And at the very least, you ought to be using a strongly-typed `string[]` instead of `Array`. That said, this version of your code might work for you:

```
string[] response_array = post_response.Split('|');
resultSpan.InnerHtml += "<OL> \n";
resultSpan.InnerHtml += "<LI>" + response_array[6] + "&nbsp;</LI> \n";
resultSpan.InnerHtml += "</OL> \n";
```

If that doesn't address your question, you should improve your question by being more specific, and also including the exact text of any warnings or errors you get.

EDIT: use `5` as the array index instead of `6` if your original data example showed the whole result of the call to `Split()` (i.e. you mis-numbered the array indexes).

Comment: @JeanF.: I respectfully disagree with the suggestion to use "var". The use of "var" in contexts where the inferred type is not obvious from reading the code has no place in good, readable C# code. I prefer the .NET naming conventions, but I'd rather not further disorient a questioner by changing variable names on them.

Comment: I understand your point of view but string.Split returns obviously a string[]. The type can be easily inferred. Using "var" makes the code easier to maintain and doesn't really impact readability. Re-sharper and StyleCop seem to agree with me but both consideration are right I guess.

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for the answer, I am geting the following error:Error 6 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Array'

Comment: Don't use Array as a type, Array itself doesn't have an indexer. Use a base class like string[], int[], ...

Comment: Thank you Jean, my issue got solved, and thank you Peter, your code work with the suggestion Jean gave. Much appreciated.